# BufferedReader in not throwing an exception after connection to socket ends

Tags: java, sockets, exception, connection, bufferedreader

I use a bufferedReader to read output from a server in my client when the button is pressed, it works fine, however I can't get it to use method errorHandling when the connection closes - I wrap in(bufferedreader object).readLine in try/catch but it does NOT throw an exception, nor does out.checkError returns true when connection fails. The program just completely freezes and doesn't reach the last catch if connection ends.

```
        if(source==button) {
        String back = "";

        if(out.checkError()){
            errorHandling("I/O Closed");
            return;
        }

        switch(currentOp){
            case(0):
                out.println("R "+input.getText());
                break;
            case(1):
                out.println("P "+input.getText());
                break;
            case(2):
                out.println("M "+input.getText());
                break;
        }

        try{

            if((back=in.readLine())==null) throw new SocketServerException();
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            errorHandling("I/O Closed");
            return;
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like the connection is being closed.

Comment: Yeah it is, as I shut down the server manually on my pc. I think that the problem is that readLine() reads until it reads some line, and since there is nothing to read it just hangs the program. I have no idea how to fix it though.. I tried with socket.isInputClosed etc but they all return false no matter what

Comment: Ok nvm it is NOT readline's fault, the same happens when I try to read a single char with read() - it freezes.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe is impossible. Ergo it is not happening. The peer socket must still be open. Check your observations.

Comment: Yep it is open because I close the server with ctrl+c in linux console and it does not close. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Fix what? The server not closing? That's a different question.